# How do i combine index form of 2 models together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi guys i have 2 models ( each with their own index form ). If i were to combine the both , so that i can view them as 1 form , how can i do that ?

Besides that , how can i generate the values of those 2 models at once ? NOTE : The parameters that user put into, will go through a method function to return a few other attribute values of my model.  I've seen nested_gem but it does not have any function to process whatever is given. For my code, i need to pass the value user key in to a function and return other few more attribute values.

Please help me

Comment: Dude, go and read some cool rails book please.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but let me give an example and hopefully it will help you.

Let's say you have 2 models, a Project and Tasks. A Project has many tasks and tasks belong to a project. I'm assuming that you have a helper method called current_user (like the one Devise gives you) which refers to current user.

If you want to list all the users projects in the index action of a controller let's say Projects#index you would have

```
@projects = current_user.projects
```

Now in your view you can loop through this like so

```
<% for project in @projects do %>
  <%= project.name %>
  <%= project.description %>
  <% for task in project.tasks  do %>
    <%= task.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now your view would display both the Projects and the tasks belonging to that project.

Comment: Hi Althaf Thanks for replying.

Comment: May i know how can i generate 2 models in a single form ? ( most of the nested form code ) doesn't work for me. 1st model = Generator_form and 2nd model would be the Result_form . I want to have only 1 form that comprises all the 2 models. In order to get the values for those 2 models, i need information (get via this form)